# Strip zeroes with regex in csv file

Tags: regex

I have csv file with decimal and integer numbers that represents amount of money, delimiter is semicolon. Example of file is:

```
00012,00;002200,21;00000;0000,00;0;
450000,21;056,01;0023,50;000000000000;
-032,23;-21.56;-00005630,05;
```

I have used this `\b0*([1-9][0-9]*\,|0)\b` to replace with `$1`like [this](https://regex101.com/r/DKS0ov/2).

However, the result must be:

```
12,00;2200,21;;0,00;;
450000,21;56,01;23,50;;
-32,23;-21.56;-5630,05;
```

So, if number is integer and has from 1 to unlimited number of `0` digits as result need to be empty (inserted in database as NULL), but if number is decimal the result must be `0,00`.

Comment: Instead of a regex, you could use `printf` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<=;|-|^)(?:0+|(0)+(,00?)0*)(?=[1-9]\d*,|;|$)
```

Replace with `$1$2`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mi6z9m/1).

**Details**

- `(?<=;|-|^)` - start of string, `;` or `-` should be immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?:0+|(0)+(,00?)0*)` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `0+` - one or more `0` digits
  - `|` - or
  - `(0)+(,00?)0*` - one or more `0` digits with the last one captured in Group 1 (`$1`) followed with `,`, `0` and an optional `0` captured into Group 2, and then zero or more `0` digits
- `(?=[1-9]\d*,|;|$)` - there must be a digit from `1` to `9` followed with any amount of any digits and then `,` or a `;` or end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 0):

Combine more rules with |

**rule1** 0*([^0]\d*,\d*[^0])0*
**rule2** 0*(0,0)0*
**rule3** 0*(0)
**rule4** 0*([^0]\d*))
**rule5** 0*(0,\d*[^0])0*
**rule6** 0*([^0]\d*,0)0*
Be attentive how you anchor the beginning and end of number.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Perl and `printf` :

```
export LC_ALL=en_DK.UTF8 # some locale which uses commas as decimal separator

perl -Mlocale -nle '@fields = 
  map { if (/,/) {
          sprintf "%.2f", $_
        } else {
          $_+=0; 
          $_ ? $_ : "NULL"
        }
      } split /;/;
  print join(";", @fields)' test.csv
```

Output:

```
12,00;2200,21;NULL;0,00;NULL
450000,21;56,01;23,50;NULL
-32,23;-21,56;-5630,05
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use lookahead and lookbehind, this one should do the trick:

```
(?<=(?:^|;)-?)0+(?=\d)
```

Explanation:

- Positive lookbehind group, containing:

  - a non-capturing group containing either a line start or a semicolon
  - an optional minus sign.
- at least one zero
- Positive lookahead group containing at least one decimal character.

This will match all the zeroes and nothing else, so you can just do a regex replace of the matches with an empty string.

Tested:

https://regex101.com/r/2a2q5h/1